# Populate Transient property

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate

I have an entity FamilyEntity which contains a transient field HouseEntity and a non transient field houseId.

```
@Column
@NotNull
@Type(type = "uuid-char")
private UUID houseId;

@Transient
private HouseEntity house;
```

How can I load the HouseEntity (and avoid LazyInitalizationExcepetion) *without* removing the transient annotation from HouseEntity? (It's older code where it would be rough to remove transient)